# Não consigo incrementar minha variável sem resetar o código

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um jogo de adivinhação em JavaScript onde o usuário tem três tentativas pra adivinhar um número aleatório entre 1 e 10, só que durante o teste, sempre que eu erro a primeira tentativa, eu incremento a variável tentativa, mas o código termina de rodar. O que estou errando ?

Segue o código

```js
var chute = document.getElementById("chute")
var numero
var tentativa

function aleatorio() {

  numero = parseInt(1 + Math.random() * 10)
  var chute2 = parseInt(chute.value)
  tentativa = 0;

  if (chute2 != numero || tentativa != 2) {
    alert("Você errou! Tente de novo")
    document.getElementById("adivinha_form").reset();
  } else if (chute2 != numero && tentativa == 2) {
    alert("Suas chances acabaram! O número correto é " + numero)
  } else if (chute2 == numero) {
    alert("Parabéns! Você acertou")
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Adivinhador</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Adivinhador</h1>
  <form name="adivinha" id="adivinha_form" action="#">
    <p>
      Seu chute: <br>
      <input type="text" id="chute" name="chute">
    </p>

    <button onclick="aleatorio()" reset="true">Arriscar</button>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adivinhacao.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu tentei alterar o mínimo de coisas possíveis no teu código, primeiramente retirei o `form`, acho desnecessário nesse caso, coloquei a variável `tentativa` fora da função e incremento ela conforme o usuário vai errando o número, sempre que o usuário acertar ou acabar suas tentativas, da o `alert` respectivo e zera o número de tentativas, qualquer dúvida pode comentar, espero que te ajude.

```js
var tentativa = 0;

function aleatorio() {
  var numero = parseInt(1 + Math.random() * 10);
  var chute2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("chute").value);
  if (chute2 != numero && tentativa != 2) {
    alert("Você errou! Tente de novo");
    tentativa = tentativa + 1;
  } else if (chute2 != numero && tentativa == 2) {
    alert("Suas chances acabaram! O número correto é " + numero);
    tentativa = 0;
  } else if (chute2 == numero) {
    alert("Parabéns! Você acertou");
    tentativa = 0;
  }
  console.clear();
  console.log("Número:" + numero);
  console.log("Chute:" + chute2);
  console.log("Tentativas:" + tentativa);
  document.getElementById("chute").value = "";
  document.getElementById("chute").focus();

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Adivinhador</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Adivinhador</h1>
  <p>
    Seu chute: <br>
    <input type="text" id="chute" name="chute">
  </p>
  <button onclick="aleatorio()">Arriscar</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adivinhacao.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```